# ReactJS, axios - Blocked by CORS Policy from local with react-scripts start command

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a very annoying problem. i've tried all method to solve but all doesnt work. I start my local reactjs frontend project, i want to communicate with backend that hosted locally in the same computer. This is my react start command :
[image]

I've set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers too.
[image]

It seems put headers to axios doesnt change anything. How to solve this? coz i cant continue my project because of this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: It doesn't work because the headers must be set on the server, not in the client.

Answer (score -3):

OMG.. just found a great solution. 
What i need to do is just install this chrome extension :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf